# PayPal Webhooks for Wix.com checkout

Tags: paypal, velo

I am in the unfortunate position of trying to integrate with Wix, and their "eCommerce" system. I cant seem to find any Wix documentation that suggests they have webhooks for when an immediate payment is taken through the store front.

I have found lots of documentation for PayPal Rest API webhooks and on the surface this looked perfect. But it would seem that PayPal dont fire webhook events for "Checkout" only for full API integrations.

So what should I be using to get notifications of payments on the Wix eCommerce system when integrating with PayPal.

- PayPal IPN's
- PayPal Webhooks (this really does not seem to work)
- Somethings from Wix.com that I am not aware of?
- None of the above / Something completely different

Comment: I would also like to know what the deal with this is. It seems Wix have Webhooks https://dev.wix.com/docs/infrastructure/webhook/?search_query=webhooks#overview ... but they seem to be specifically for apps, not the ECommerce.